# How to pass a string argument to a function from global-set-key definition inside .emacs

Tags: shell, interactive, defun

Inside my `.emacs` file I have these two functions:

```
(defun bh/switch-to-vs ()
  (interactive)
  (universal-argument)
  (shell "*vs*"))

(defun bh/switch-to-android ()
  (interactive)
  (universal-argument)
  (shell "*android*"))
```

I bind keys to those two methods like this:

```
(global-set-key [f1] 'bh/switch-to-vs)
(global-set-key [f2] 'bh/switch-to-android)
```

All working fine, but I prefer defining a function which takes the name of the shell as an argument. I need something like this:

```
(defun bh/switch-to (shell_name)
  (interactive)
  (universal-argument)
  (shell shell_name))
```

However, I have trouble calling this method from inside `(global-set-key [f1] 'bh/switch-to vs)` // not sure how to call it, getting various errors.

How to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```lisp
(defun example-one (&optional shell-name)
"Example where `current-prefix-arg' is hard-coded to be non-nil."
  (interactive)
  (let ((current-prefix-arg t)
        (shell-name (or shell-name (read-string "Shell Name:  "))))
    (shell shell-name)))

(defun example-two (&optional shell-name)
"Example where the user has the option of using a universal argument:  C-u"
  (interactive)
  (let ((shell-name (or shell-name (read-string "Shell Name:  "))))
    (shell shell-name)))

(global-set-key [f1] 'example-one)

(global-set-key [f2] 'example-two)
```

Comment: Thank you but what I want to do is something like this: `(global-set-key [f1] '(example-one "android"))` - If I do this I get an error message `Wrong type argument: commandp, (example-one "android")`. What is wrong here?

Comment: I have found the needed code, it is: `(global-set-key [f1] (lambda () (interactive) (example-one "android")))`